# Terminal Specific Aliases

Tags: terminal, zsh, vim

Is there a way to have a terminal specific alias?

For example: I want to use "vim" and "nvim" to refer to vanilla vim on terminal.app but I want "vim" and "nvim" to refer to NeoVim on Iterm2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to inspect the environment to see if suitable variables
exist to distinguish the two; here is terminal brand X

```
% env | grep -i -E 'terminal|iterm'
ITERM_PROFILE=small-white
ITERM_SESSION_ID=w3t0p0:BF718B9E-F185-44FF-9BC4-4F071F378015
```

and then brand Y

```
% env | grep -i -E 'terminal|iterm'
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
```

However, this is not perfectly reliable should environment variables
from one end up in the other; with Terminal.app not running if in
iTerm one runs:

```
% print $ITERM_SESSION_ID
w3t0p0:BF718B9E-F185-44FF-9BC4-4F071F378015
% open -a Terminal.app
```

Then over in the just launched Terminal.app one might see:

```
% env | grep -i -E 'terminal|iterm'
ITERM_SESSION_ID=w3t0p0:BF718B9E-F185-44FF-9BC4-4F071F378015
ITERM_PROFILE=small-white
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
```

as Terminal.app has inherited iTerm.app environment variables by way of
the `open` call. This will likely not be a problem if you never do that.

Anyways, if you trust the environment variables to be correct, then

```
if [[ $TERM_PROGRAM == "Apple_Terminal" ]]; then
   print "I'm a terminal!"
else
   print "I'm not a PC"
fi
```

should distinguish the two, assuming that anything not Apple terminal is
iterm. This may fail for remote SSH connections, or yet other terminal
programs (e.g. Alacritty) in which case you will need to season the code with more logic.

### Another method

Another method would be to change the startup program of one or both
of the terminal programs to run a small wrapper script that sets
some (hopefully) custom environment variable and then executes the
real shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
THIS_IS_TERMINAL_DOT_APP=1 ; export THIS_IS_TERMINAL_DOT_APP
exec /bin/zsh
```

... but this could also inherit environment variables from somewhere else.

### Requires More Research

The process tree (starting via `$PPID`) could be walked to find the parent process. This however might detect `tmux` which would require additional code to figure out what terminal application the particular `tmux` is running under, if anything.

Comment: `$PPID` is rather more reliable. If screen/tmux is involved, environment variables like `ITERM_xxx` reflect where the session was started, not what it's attached to now. Most terminal emulators don't set environment variables — iTerm is one of the few that do. One case where environment variables work but not `$PPID` is when a shell is started by another shell, but that's uncommon.